# MASM, de carácter en registro a número en variable

Tags: ensamblador, masm

Tengo un código de MASM que, groso modo, se encarga de recoger información de los registros y poner sus valores en una ventana.

Siendo aStr, bStr, cStr y dStr los textos de "presentación" de cada registro y aStrv, bStrv… los valores de éstos, simplemente recoge si haces click derecho o izquierdo (o pulsas una tecla con el focus), para hacer xor y limpiar registros o actualizar los valores mostrados, respectivamente. Por si lo necesitan, tienen todo el código aquí. Si no, tienen más abajo el fragmento concreto donde, a mi parecer, estaría el problema.

```
.386 
.model flat,stdcall 
option casemap:none 
WinMain proto :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD 
include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\user32.inc 
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
include \masm32\include\gdi32.inc 
include \masm32\include\rtutils.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
includelib \masm32\lib\gdi32.lib 
RGB macro red,green,blue 
        xor eax,eax 
        mov ah,blue 
        shl eax,8 
        mov ah,green 
        mov al,red 
endm 
.data 
ClassName db "Regist",0 
AppName  db "Lector de registros generales de CPU",0 
aStr  db "Registro eax: ",0 
bStr  db "Registro ebx: ",0 
cStr  db "Registro ecx: ",0 
dStr  db "Registro edx: ",0 

aStrv  dd 0b
bStrv  dword 0b
cStrv  dword 0b
dStrv  dword 0b
delayer dword 0
FontName db "Segoe UI",0 
MouseClickL db 0
MouseClickR db 0

actul db "Actualizado",0
ers db "Valores borrados",0
.data? 
hInstance HINSTANCE ? 
CommandLine LPSTR ? 
hitpoint POINT <>
.code 
 start: 
    invoke GetModuleHandle, NULL 
    mov    hInstance,eax 
    invoke GetCommandLine 
    invoke WinMain, hInstance,NULL,CommandLine, SW_SHOWDEFAULT 
    invoke ExitProcess,eax 

WinMain proc hInst:HINSTANCE,hPrevInst:HINSTANCE,CmdLine:LPSTR,CmdShow:DWORD 
    LOCAL wc:WNDCLASSEX 
    LOCAL msg:MSG 
    LOCAL hwnd:HWND 
    mov   wc.cbSize,SIZEOF WNDCLASSEX 
    mov   wc.style, CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW 
    mov   wc.lpfnWndProc, OFFSET WndProc 
    mov   wc.cbClsExtra,NULL 
    mov   wc.cbWndExtra,NULL 
    push  hInst 
    pop   wc.hInstance 
    mov   wc.hbrBackground,COLOR_WINDOW+1 
    mov   wc.lpszMenuName,NULL 
    mov   wc.lpszClassName,OFFSET ClassName 
    invoke LoadIcon,NULL,IDI_APPLICATION 
    mov   wc.hIcon,eax 
    mov   wc.hIconSm,eax 
    invoke LoadCursor,NULL,IDC_ARROW 
    mov   wc.hCursor,eax 
    invoke RegisterClassEx, addr wc 
    invoke CreateWindowEx,NULL,ADDR ClassName,ADDR AppName,\ 
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,0,\ 
           0,250,180,NULL,NULL,\ 
           hInst,NULL 
    mov   hwnd,eax 
    invoke ShowWindow, hwnd,SW_SHOWNORMAL 
    invoke UpdateWindow, hwnd 
    .WHILE TRUE 
                invoke GetMessage, ADDR msg,NULL,0,0 
                .BREAK .IF (!eax) 
                invoke TranslateMessage, ADDR msg 
                invoke DispatchMessage, ADDR msg 
    .ENDW 
    mov     eax,msg.wParam 
    ret 
WinMain endp 
WndProc proc hWnd:HWND, uMsg:UINT, wParam:WPARAM, lParam:LPARAM 
    LOCAL hdc:HDC 
    LOCAL ps:PAINTSTRUCT 
    LOCAL hfont:HFONT 
    .IF uMsg==WM_DESTROY 
        invoke PostQuitMessage,NULL 
    .ELSEIF uMsg==WM_LBUTTONDOWN
        mov MouseClickL,TRUE 
        invoke InvalidateRect,hWnd,NULL,TRUE 
    .ELSEIF uMsg==WM_RBUTTONDOWN
        mov MouseClickR,TRUE 
        invoke InvalidateRect,hWnd,NULL,TRUE 
    .ELSEIF uMsg==WM_CHAR
        mov MouseClickL,TRUE 
        invoke InvalidateRect,hWnd,NULL,TRUE
    .ELSEIF uMsg==WM_PAINT 
        invoke BeginPaint,hWnd, ADDR ps 
        mov    hdc,eax 
        invoke SelectObject, hdc, eax 
        mov    hfont,eax 
        RGB    0, 0, 0 
        invoke SetTextColor,hdc,eax 
        RGB    255, 255, 255 
        invoke SetBkColor,hdc,eax


;--------------------------------------------Fragmento mostrado posteriormente----------------------------------       
        update:
        mov aStrv, eax
        mov bStrv, ebx
        mov cStrv, ecx
        mov dStrv, edx    
;-------------------------------------------Fin de fragmento----------------------------------------------------

        invoke TextOut,hdc,5,5,ADDR aStr,SIZEOF aStr 
        invoke TextOut,hdc,5,30,ADDR bStr,SIZEOF bStr 
        invoke TextOut,hdc,5,55,ADDR cStr,SIZEOF cStr 
        invoke TextOut,hdc,5,80,ADDR dStr,SIZEOF cStr

        invoke TextOut,hdc,100,5,ADDR aStrv,SIZEOF aStrv 
        invoke TextOut,hdc,100,30,ADDR bStrv,SIZEOF bStrv 
        invoke TextOut,hdc,100,55,ADDR cStrv,SIZEOF cStrv 
        invoke TextOut,hdc,100,80,ADDR dStrv,SIZEOF dStrv 
        invoke SelectObject,hdc, hfont 

        .IF MouseClickL
            mov MouseClickL, FALSE
            jmp update
        .ENDIF 
        .IF MouseClickR
            mov MouseClickR, FALSE
            xor eax, eax
            xor ebx, ebx
            xor ecx, ecx
            xor edx, edx
            jmp update
        .ENDIF        
        invoke EndPaint,hWnd, ADDR ps
    .ELSE 
        invoke DefWindowProc,hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam 
        ret
    .ENDIF 
    ret
WndProc endp 
end start
```

De éste código creo que sólo es prioritaria la parte de:

```
mov aStrv, eax
mov bStrv, ebx
mov cStrv, ecx
mov dStrv, edx
```

Donde me gustaría que aStrv y todas las demás variables no recogieran símbolos como en la imagen:

[image: Los caracteres basura mostrados]

¿Cómo podría convertir la información del registro a HEX o BIN, y a su vez sacarlo como texto tipo 0x00, para evitar estos caracteres?

Comment: Tal vez su respuesta está aquí (pero en inglés) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922134/printing-out-a-number-in-assembly-language/22897576#22897576

Comment: Gracias. por lo pronto parece útil. Comprobaré su utilidad.